RULE_APPEND failed (Too many links)
I'm trying to apply the policy I got by running iptables-legacy-save using iptables-nft-restore. When I do, this I get this error. When I search for this error, all I can find is a paywalled redhat site. What does this error mean?

From RedHat page (linked to an EKS issue) : This is there to prevent Stack Overflows, EMLINK is the return signal for too many links. AWS link to issue https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/issues/2373

So effectively this means that my policy has too many jumps, or do gotos also increase the stack? Is there any way to increase this value in nf_tables? It doesn't look like it
